# Can loops and mapping be used in Cloudformation Templates to make multiple AWS Budgets with different CostFilter Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, loops, nested, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have created a Nested Cloudformation YAML template set.  It consists of the Main YAML, and the Nested YAML.

It creates 22 AWS Budgets with various aggregates of common AWS Services that I currently use.

The main file is very long, and it "feels wrong" to do it this way.
I am wondering, if I could instead use mapping and loops to accomplish the same thing?

Note:  Some Budgets have only 1 Service, while others have 4 or 5.

My 2 files are below.  They are designed to be hosted in an S3 bucket (at minimum the nested file needs to be) and then the BUDGETS.YAML file would be used to create a new Stack.

The Console looks like this when the Script is executed now:

[Screenshot of the AWS Budget Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oOiI.png)

Here is the code for the 'CreateBudget.yaml' file, which is the Nested Stack that needs to be hosted on S3 and is 'called' by the main stack:

```html
Description: Create-New-Monthly-Budget
Parameters:
    NamingPrefix:
        Type: String
    BudgetAmount:
        Type: Number
    ServiceFilters:
        Type: CommaDelimitedList
    AlertEmail:
        Type: String
Resources:
  NewBudget:
    Type: AWS::Budgets::Budget
    Properties:
      Budget:
        BudgetName: !Sub ${NamingPrefix}-Monthly-Budget
        BudgetLimit:
          Amount: !Ref BudgetAmount
          Unit: USD
        TimeUnit: MONTHLY
        TimePeriod:
          Start: 1225864800
          End: 1926864800
        BudgetType: COST
        CostFilters:
          Service:
            !Ref ServiceFilters
        CostTypes:
          IncludeCredit: true
          IncludeDiscount: true
          IncludeOtherSubscription: true
          IncludeRecurring: true
          IncludeRefund: true
          IncludeSubscription: true
          IncludeSupport: true
          IncludeTax: true
          IncludeUpfront: true
          UseAmortized: false
          UseBlended: false
      NotificationsWithSubscribers:
        - Notification:
            NotificationType: FORECASTED
            ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
            Threshold: 100
          Subscribers:
            - SubscriptionType: EMAIL
              Address: !Ref AlertEmail
        - Notification:
            NotificationType: ACTUAL
            ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
            Threshold: 75
          Subscribers:
            - SubscriptionType: EMAIL
              Address: !Ref AlertEmail
        - Notification:
            NotificationType: ACTUAL
            ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
            Threshold: 50
          Subscribers:
            - SubscriptionType: EMAIL
              Address: !Ref AlertEmail
        - Notification:
            NotificationType: ACTUAL
            ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
            Threshold: 25
          Subscribers:
            - SubscriptionType: EMAIL
              Address: !Ref AlertEmail
Outputs:
  NewBudgetName:
    Value: !Ref NewBudget
```

And here is the Main Stack file, which you can host with S3 or you can just Upload it when you create the Stack. I called this Budgets.yaml but it can be called anything since it's not referenced by the other file.

```html
Description: Create-Multiple-Budgets
Parameters:
  AlertEmail:
    Type: String
    Default: "my_email_address@gmail.com"
  s3TemplateURL:
    Type: String
    Default: "https://my-s3-bucket-name.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/budgets/CreateBudget.yaml"
Resources:
  
  # 01
  NestedCallEC2:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "EC2"
        BudgetAmount: 170
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon Elastic Block Store
            - Savings Plans for AWS Compute usage
            - Amazon Elastic Load Balancing
            - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL

  # 02
  NestedCallRDS:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "RDS"
        BudgetAmount: 80
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon Relational Database Service
            - Amazon DynamoDB
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL

  # 03
  NestedCallCloudWatch:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "CloudWatch"
        BudgetAmount: 20
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - AmazonCloudWatch
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 04
  NestedCallSecurity:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Security"
        BudgetAmount: 10
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - AWS WAF
            - AWS Secrets Manager
            - AWS Security Hub
            - AWS Key Management Service
            - Amazon Cognito
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 05
  NestedCallRoute53:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Route53"
        BudgetAmount: 5
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon Route 53
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 06
  NestedCallSNS:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "SNS"
        BudgetAmount: 5
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon Simple Notification Service
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 07
  NestedCallPipeline:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Pipeline"
        BudgetAmount: 1
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - AWS Data Pipeline
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 08
  NestedCallGlacier:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Glacier"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon Glacier
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 09
  NestedCallMisc:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Misc"
        BudgetAmount: 1
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - AWS Cost Explorer
            - AWS Systems Manager
            - AWS Budgets
            - AWS Elemental MediaStore
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 10
  NestedCallStorage:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Storage"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon Simple Storage Service
            - Amazon Elastic File System
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 11
  NestedCallCloudFront:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "CloudFront"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon CloudFront
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 12
  NestedCallKinesis:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Kinesis"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon Kinesis
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 13
  NestedCallAthena:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Athena"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon Athena
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 14
  NestedCallAPIGateway:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "APIGateway"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon API Gateway
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 15
  NestedCallAmplify:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Amplify"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - AWS Amplify
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 16
  NestedCallLambda:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Lambda"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - AWS Lambda
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL

  # 17
  NestedCallSES:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "SES"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon Simple Email Service
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 18
  NestedCallDevSupport:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "DevSupport"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - AWS Support (Developer)
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 19
  NestedCallAnalytics:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "Analytics"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - AWS Glue
            - Amazon QuickSight
            - AWS X-Ray
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 20
  NestedCallSQS:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "SQS"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Amazon Simple Queue Service
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 21
  NestedCallDataTransfer:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "DataTransfer"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - AWS Data Transfer
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL
  
  # 22
  NestedCallIQ:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertEmail: !Ref AlertEmail
        NamingPrefix: "IQ"
        BudgetAmount: 2
        ServiceFilters: !Join 
          - ','
          - - Professional services provided by AWS IQ Expert
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
      TemplateURL: !Ref s3TemplateURL


Outputs:
  BudgetName01:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallEC2
  BudgetARN01:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallEC2.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName02:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallRDS
  BudgetARN02:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallRDS.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName03:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallCloudWatch
  BudgetArn03:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallCloudWatch.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName04:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallSecurity
  BudgetArn04:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallSecurity.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName05:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallRoute53
  BudgetArn05:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallRoute53.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName06:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallSNS
  BudgetArn06:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallSNS.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName07:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallPipeline
  BudgetArn07:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallPipeline.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName08:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallGlacier
  BudgetArn08:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallGlacier.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName09:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallMisc
  BudgetArn09:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallMisc.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName10:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallStorage
  BudgetArn10:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallStorage.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName11:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallCloudFront
  BudgetArn11:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallCloudFront.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName12:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallKinesis
  BudgetArn12:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallKinesis.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName13:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallAthena
  BudgetArn13:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallAthena.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName14:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallAPIGateway
  BudgetArn14:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallAPIGateway.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName15:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallAmplify
  BudgetArn15:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallAmplify.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName16:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallLambda
  BudgetArn16:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallLambda.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName17:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallSES
  BudgetArn17:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallSES.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName18:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallDevSupport
  BudgetArn18:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallDevSupport.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName19:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallAnalytics
  BudgetArn19:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallAnalytics.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName20:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallSQS
  BudgetArn20:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallSQS.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName21:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallDataTransfer
  BudgetArn21:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallDataTransfer.Outputs.NewBudgetName
  BudgetName22:
    Value: !Ref NestedCallIQ
  BudgetArn22:
    Value: !GetAtt NestedCallIQ.Outputs.NewBudgetName
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the issue? There are no loops in CFN, as you have in terraform for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFormation **doesn't have a concept like loops**.

But you could use so called **Macros** to tackle this problem. Here is an [example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Count) that might help you.